# Modifying a list while iterating over it - why not?

Tags: python, list

Almost every tutorial and SO answer on this topic insists that you should never modify a list while iterating over it, but I can't see why this is such a bad thing if the code is valid. For example:

```
while len(mylist) > 0:
    print mylist.pop()
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Note: instead of this you can just do `while mylist:`

Comment: Oh? That's so elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
while len(mylist) > 0:
    print mylist.pop()
```

You are not iterating over the list. You are each time checking an atomic condition.

Also:

```
while len(mylist) > 0:
```

can be rewritten as:

```
while len(mylist):
```

which can be rewritten as:

```
while mylist:
```

Comment: *face palm* Of course, that makes sense. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 9):

The reason to why you should never modify a list while iterating over it is for example, you're iterating over a list of 20 digits, and if you hit an even number you pop it off the list and carry on till you have a list of just odd numbers.

Now, say this is your sample data `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]`, and you start iterating over it. First iteration, and the number is `1` so you continue, the following number is `2` so you pop it off, and rinse and repeat.  You now feel the application worked correctly as the resultant list is `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]`.

Now let's say your sample data is `[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 15, 17, 18, 20]` and you run the same piece of code as before and mutate the original list while iterating through it. Your resultant list is `[1, 4, 5, 7, 10, 11, 13, 15, 15, 17, 20]` which is clearly incorrect as there are still even numbers contained in the list.

If you are planning on mutating the list while iterating through it like so

```
for elem in lst:
    # mutate list in place
```

You should rather change it to

```
for elem in lst[:]:
    # mutate list in place
```

The `[:]` syntax creates a new list that is an exact copy of the original list, so that you can happily mutate the original list without affecting what you're processing as you won't have any unintended side-effects from mutating the list you're iterating through.

If your list is rather sizable, instead of creating a new list and stepping through it look at using generator expressions or write your own generator for your list if you feel the need so that you do not waste memory and CPU cycles.

Comment: To copy a list it's much nicer to use "list(src)" rather than "src[:]"

Comment: @MariaZverina: `mylist[:]` is a standard Python idiom.

Comment: @katriealex just because something is relatively "standard" doesn't make it right. I'm familiar with the idiom but it is too Perlesque and not friendly to Python newbies. There is no reason not to switch now ... anyone who can follow mylist[:] will also be able to follow list(mylist) ... and everyone else will thank you. :-)

Answer (score 7):

I'll go into a little bit more detail *why* you shouldn't iterate over a list. Naturally, by that I mean

```
for elt in my_list:
    my_list.pop()
```

or similar idioms.

First, we need to think about what Python's `for` loop does. Since you can attempt to iterate over any object, Python doesn't necessarily know *how* to iterate over whatever you've given it. So there is a list (heh) of things it tries to do to work out how to present the values one-by-one. And the first thing it does is checks for an `__iter__` method on the object and -- if it exists -- calls it.

The result of this call will then be an *iterable* object; that is, one with a `next` method. Now we're good to go: just call `next` repeatedly until `StopIteration` is raised.

Why is this important? Well, because the `__iter__` method has actually to look at the data structure to find the values, and remember some internal state so that it knows where to look next. But if you change the data structure then `__iter__` has no way of knowing that you've been fiddling, so it will blithely keep on trying to grab new data. What this means in practise is that you will probably skip elements of the list.

---

It's always nice to justify this sort of claim with a look at the source code. From `listobject.c`:

```
static PyObject *
listiter_next(listiterobject *it)
{
    PyListObject *seq;
    PyObject *item;

    assert(it != NULL);
    seq = it->it_seq;
    if (seq == NULL)
        return NULL;
    assert(PyList_Check(seq));

    if (it->it_index < PyList_GET_SIZE(seq)) {
        item = PyList_GET_ITEM(seq, it->it_index);
        ++it->it_index;
        Py_INCREF(item);
        return item;
    }

    Py_DECREF(seq);
    it->it_seq = NULL;
    return NULL;
}
```

Note in particular that it really does simulate a C-style `for` loop, with `it->it_index` playing the part of the index variable. In particular, if you delete an item from the list then you won't update `it_index`, so you may skip a value.

Answer (score 4):

You code doesn't iterate over the list.

```
for i in mylist:
  print mylist.pop()
```