# Removing words containing digits from a given string

Tags: python, regex, list, iteration

I'm trying to write a simple program that removes all words containing digits from a received string.

Here is my current implementation:

```
import re

def checkio(text):

    text = text.replace(",", " ").replace(".", " ") .replace("!", " ").replace("?", " ").lower()
    counter = 0
    words = text.split()

    print words

    for each in words:
        if bool(re.search(r'\d', each)):
            words.remove(each)

    print words

checkio("1a4 4ad, d89dfsfaj.")
```

However, when I execute this program, I get the following output:

```
['1a4', '4ad', 'd89dfsfaj']
['4ad']
```

I can't figure out why `'4ad'` is printed in the second line as it contains digits and should have been removed from the list.  Any ideas?

Comment: Add your expected output too

Comment: You're modifying the list while iterating over it. See this question for why you shouldn't do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812272/modifying-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-why-not

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What are your constraints and conditions?

Comment: It's not so much about constraints as understanding why this is going wrong.  I see now that I'm modifying a list that I'm iterating over and that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your regular expression does what you want, you can do this to avoid removing while iterating.

```
import re

def checkio(text):

    text = re.sub('[,\.\?\!]', ' ', text).lower()
    words = [w for w in text.split() if not re.search(r'\d', w)]
    print words ## prints [] in this case
```

Also, note that I simplified your `text = text.replace(...)` line.

Additionally, if you do not need to reuse your `text` variable, you can use regex to split it directly.

```
import re

def checkio(text):

    words = [w for w in re.split('[,.?!]', text.lower()) if w and not re.search(r'\d', w)]
    print words ## prints [] in this case
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing for alpha numeric strings why not use `isalnum()` instead of regex ?

```
In [1695]: x = ['1a4', '4ad', 'd89dfsfaj']

In [1696]: [word for word in x if not word.isalnum()]
Out[1696]: []
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible through using `re.sub`, `re.search` and `list_comprehension`.

```
>>> import re
>>> def checkio(s):
        print([i for i in re.sub(r'[.,!?]', '', s.lower()).split() if not re.search(r'\d', i)])


>>> checkio("1a4 4ad, d89dfsfaj.")
[]
>>> checkio("1a4 ?ad, d89dfsfaj.")
['ad']
```

Answer (score -1):

So apparently what happens is a concurrent access error. Namely - you are deleting an element while traversing the array.

At the first iteration we have words = ['1a4', '4ad', 'd89dfsfaj']. Since '1a4' has a number, we remove it.
Now, words = ['4ad','d89dfsfaj']. However, at the second iteration, the current word is now 'd89dfsfaj' and we remove it. What happens is that we skip '4ad', because it is now at index 0 and the current pointer for the for cycle is at 1.

Comment: re.search returns a re.MatchObject