# table.remove removes certain elements but not all

Tags: python, pandas, list, nlp

I'm trying to remove elements from a list (list is stored in a pandas dataframe) with `.remove()`. The base idea is that i iterate through all the rows in the dataframe then every element in the row (=list), and check whether that particular element is a keeper or a "goner"

```
data=dict()
data=pd.read_csv('raw_output_v2.csv', names=['ID','Body'])
data['Body']=data['Body'].apply(eval)  
keyword_dict={}
for row in tqdm(data['Body'], desc="building dict"):
    for word in row:
        if word in keyword_dict:
            keyword_dict[word]+=1
        else:
            keyword_dict[word]=1 

new_df=remove_sparse_words_from_df(data, keyword_dict, cutoff=1_000_000)
```

And here is the important stuff:

```
def remove_sparse_words_from_df(df, term_freq, cutoff=1):
    i=0
    for row in tqdm(df['Body'],desc="cleaning df"):
        for word in row:
            if term_freq[word]<=cutoff:
                row.remove(word)
            else:
                continue
    return df
```

I've uploaded a short example csv to be used here: https://pastebin.com/g25bHCC7.

My problem is: the `remove_sparse_words_from_df` function removes some occurances of the words that fall below cutoff, but not all. Example: the word "clean" occurs ~10k in the original dataframe (data), after running `remove_sparse_words_from_df` about 2k still remains. Same with other words.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're modifying your list (`row.remove`) while iterating over it (`for word in row:`). You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812272/modifying-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-why-not), [here](https://blog.finxter.com/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating/) and [here](https://blog.finxter.com/daily-python-puzzle-how-to-modify-sequence-while-iterating/), why this may be a problem:

> Modifying a sequence while iterating over it can cause undesired behavior due to the way the iterator is build. To avoid this problem, a simple solution is to iterate over a copy of the list... using the slice notation with default values **list_1[:]**

```py
    ...
    for row in tqdm(df['Body'],desc="cleaning df"):
        for word in row[:]:
            if term_freq[word]<=cutoff:
                row.remove(word)
    ...
```

Cutoff set as **1_000_000**

```
                   ID Body
0  (1483785165, 2009)   []
1  (1538280431, 2010)   []
2  (1795044103, 2010)   []
...
...
```